# Plotting box plots in python without grouping the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, list-comprehension, boxplot

I want to plot a box plot for a variable in a data frame `xldata['yaxis_data']` according to 1,0 mapping stored in another array (`one_zero_map`).

I have a working code for this I am just not sure if this is the best way. Any help would be great.

Reason I am unsure is I am guessing there should be a direct way for boxplot to understand what I want if I input directly `one_zero_map` and `xldata['yaxis_data']` without creating good_ones and bad_ones and then putting them in a list called `final_list`

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

good_ones=[val for ind, val in zip(one_zero_map,xldata['yaxis_data']) if  ind==1]
bad_ones=[val for ind, val in zip(one_zero_map,xldata['yaxis_data']) if ind==0]

final_list=[good_ones,bad_ones]

plt.boxplot(final_list)
```

Just to be more clear on what I am looking for, I am looking for Python equivalent of [R](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/boxplot.html) which is like this

```
# Boxplot of MPG by Car Cylinders 
boxplot(mpg~cyl,data=mtcars, main="Car Milage Data", 
xlab="Number of Cylinders", ylab="Miles Per Gallon")
```

or phython equivalent of graphlab as

```
sales.show(view='BoxWhisker Plot',x='zipcode',y='price')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`boxplot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html) method directly from pandas DataFrames. This code is equivalent to your R example:

```
# statsmodels only needed to get the R mtcars dataset
import statsmodels.api as sm
mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset('mtcars').data

mtcars.boxplot('mpg', by='cyl')
```

Comment: Works great. (Although gives some problem because I have NAs in my data but I can fix it).  When I search for 'python boxplot' on google, first few results are only plotly and matplotlib but this simple and elegant solution does not seem to appear. I guess the key is to search for 'pandas boxplot'